# drunk and drunken

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, adjectives, participles

I want to know the difference between word **drunk** and **drunken**.

I looked up the dictionary and found that two words have same meaning, someone drinks alcohol too much.

About **drunk**, it could be interpreted as two meanings, one is meaning of past participle form of verb **drink** and the other is meaning of adjective (also someone drinks alcohol too much).

Here, I am curious about usage of two adjectives **drunk** and **drunken**.

My teacher said

> "He was **drunken**" is ungrammatical, whereas "a **drunken** driver" and "He
>   was **drunk**" are grammatical.

I'm really curious that why **he was drunken** is not accepted but **he was drunk** is okay.

Answer (score 6):

We have the adjective **drunk** which means "inebriated, physically and mentally showing the effects of having consumed too much alcohol".

It is used as a predicate complement:

> That man is very drunk. Stop serving him and find him a taxicab.
>
> His car was broadsided by a man driving drunk.

It is used also as an adjective before the noun:

> He was broadsided by a drunk driver.

**drunken** is an older form of the past participle of the verb **drink**, and it hasn't been used much as past-participle for the last 200 years though it exists alongside **drunk** as an adjective.

> You  drunken hooligans, get out of my donut shop now, or I'll call the police!

Comment: It feels better to me to say **drunken hooligans** than **drunk hooligans**. Do you agree? Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The past participle is "drunk", but it can also be a verb noun or adjective. It generally means intoxicated, and is usually the predicate adjective, "He was drunk."

"Drunken" is only ever an adjective (its use as the past participle is obsolete). I have drunk the water, while my drunken father has drunk another beer.

Drunken is characterized as lots of drinking. You might talk about a drunken party.

Answer (score 0):

As to the reasoning behind the difference, there is no reason that has present-day relevance. A great deal of grammar and diction has to do with word-history (of which, in this case, I am ignorant) and pure tradition!  There is a poem by Rimbaud (I think) called "The Drunken Boat,"  and one says "He went on a drunken rant," but "He was drunk."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).